# screenshotButton() does not render styleColorBar from formatStyle on Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, format, dt, shinyscreenshot

When I want to take a screenshot of a Shiny page using the shinyscreenshot library, the ColorBar style does not appear in the screen.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyscreenshot)

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(datatable(iris['Sepal.Length']) %>% formatStyle(1, background = styleColorBar(iris['Sepal.Length'], 'blue')),
                        screenshotButton()
                        ),
         server = function(input, output, session) {})
```

[Shiny application and screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRBe7.png)

Thank you

Comment: Try the **capture** package (<https://github.com/dreamRs/capture>).

Comment: Merci Stéphane !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it can help others: use the capture package as suggested by Stéphane instead of shinyscreenshot, but if you want to capture a fluidRow it will not behave well, so it’s better to add a div around that fluidRow and capture the div.